# Building content only/dependency meta package using csproj and nuget (teamcity build)

Tags: nuget

I have a project that pulls in dependencies and adds some code templates, but isntalling the resulting nuget causes my project to get polluted by an empty dll.

I tried making a .nuspec, but I find the documentation lacking on this topic.

I ran `nuget spec` and deleted the irrelevant metadata, then added a `files` section, with a single `file` entry:

```
<file src="src/*.pp" target="dst/" />
```

But the resulting .nuget still contains an empty dll under `lib/net462`.

The pp file is placed into `Content/src` in the nuget, but I am guessing the target will be applied properly when installed.